# React useEffect Hook eslint best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, eslint

I have a useEffect hook inside my component as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (tokenTransferSuccess.success) {
      const message = systemMessage({
        senderName: tokenTransferSuccess.senderName,
        tokenName: tokenTransferSuccess.tokenName,
        receiverMessageId: tokenTransferSuccess.receiverMessageId as string,
        receiverName: tokenTransferSuccess.receiverName,
        nftId: tokenTransferSuccess.nftId,
        tokenAmount: tokenTransferSuccess.amount,
        transactionId: tokenTransferSuccess.transaction?._id,
      });
      sendSystemMessage(message); //this is a function
    }
  }, [
    tokenTransferSuccess.success,
  ]);
```

Whenever success changes the effect is triggered and a sendSystemMessage is called. But eslint gives me the following suggestion/warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'sendSystemMessage'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

So when I add this function into the dependency the warning goes away. I just wanted to know if this is a good practice. Since sendSystemMessage is a function, I don't understand why this should be added as a dependency. The code currently works as expected.

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies

Comment: Yes you should add the function to the `useEffect`

Comment: But what about the scenario when I don't want to add any dependency, i.e it should trigger when the component mounts (useEffect(()=>[])), but it still asks me to add it in the dependency?

Answer (score -1):

If you are confident in your dependencies arr and just don't like to see this warning

so, just add missing lines of eslintConfig in `package.json`

```json
    "eslintConfig": {
        "rules": {
            "no-unused-vars": "off",
            "no-unused-expressions": "off",
            "no-unreachable": "off",
            "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"
        },
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: The warning produced by the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule is meant to ensure you're correctly using the dependency arrays. If such a warning is encountered, it should be properly address by adding the missing dependencies in the array, or removing the dependency altogether, rather than disabling the rule altogether.